# The rendered animation has no sound (I have added sound before rendered). Have I skip something?

Tags: audio

I have followed this tutorial to add sound: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbafWSIYIZw
I have tried many times but the animation has no sound after rendered. (I mean it's a silence animation like the one that I rendered before adding sound)

There are the settings that I use(and the device for rendered is CPU):
[image]

[image]

If anyone know what happened or what I skipped, please tell me!

Comment: Try re-importing your render to the VSE to check that the sound is not there. Otherwise it could be your media player?

Comment: ＠3pointedit Does VSE means video sequence editor? If yes, yes after rendered the sound is still there in VSE. It's not the media player's problem, I thought(because it is an mp4 file:)

Comment: Yes the VSE is the Video Sequence Editor. I was suggesting that you try bringing the rendred clip into a clean VSE timeline and turn on the waveform for the audio (Properties panel on the right). If the newly rendered media has a waveform and plays sound then there is something wrong with your media player or the media player doesn't like mp3. Have you tried AAC instead?

Comment: I have the same problem, here is the setup that works for me: Output > FFmpeg. Encoding > Presets > H264 in MP4. Codec H264, Output Quality > Lossless. Audio Codec > AAC (bitrate 192 ou maximum 384). I work on Mac, I can't read the result with Quicktime, so I convert it with MacX Video Converter Pro.

Comment: @ 3pointedit You are the lifesaver! The sound works after I choose AAC. It was the problem of my media player maybe because I work on Mac. Thank you so much!  @moonboots Thanks for sharing the setup! You really help me, too :)